# Is it possible to check if an aspx page is an image

Tags: html, asp.net, image, types

I need to check If an aspx page is an image or an HTML page.
In other words is it possible to get the content type of a web page via URL.
Or are there characteristics by which it is possible to determine what the content type is.

Comment: Without actually connecting?

Comment: @JaimeTorres yes. But Adam Millers awnser was enough to clear ther problem. Thanks anyway !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code behind, try some testing on Response.ContentType.  Here's Microsoft's description of it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208(v=vs.90).aspx

It really depends on the content-type HTTP header, as CodeCaster mentioned, and I believe there are a number of those that apply to images of different formats.
In the end, though, there's no way to know for sure, as you never know what you're going to get from a web request.

Answer (score 1):

> are there characteristics by wich it is possible to determine what the content type is

By inspecting the `content-type` HTTP response header.